# Translation of Metal methods into the kernel Core Image language

Tags: swift, kernel, shader, metal, cifilter

My task implies to interfere with the VHS cassettes, descending lines of distortion from above of the screen.
I found a shader on this link https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtBXDt
, and I do not understand how not to get lost in the coordinates. When trying to replace UV on destcoord() I will climb the error immediately.

`let kernel = CIColorKernel(source: "//Kernel code String")`

I apologize to the public with such... Really want to find an answer...

Comment: Please provide your shader code.

Comment: This code here https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtBXDt .Thank you very much that you answered me. I also opened the Kernel language specification, but there is a dark forest for me.

Comment: I try to make it like ` kernel vec4 vhsTracking(__ sample image, __sample time ...?) { vec2 uv = destCoord(); ...?}`